# Setting up Azure Cognitive Search using @azure/search-document vs. using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

My team is working on implementing Azure Cognitive Search on one of our websites. We notice that there are 2 ways to set it up: one way is using Azure Portal to import the data, create the index, and expose the APIs that do not require coding at all; another way is to use the @azure/search-documents library which requires a lot of coding to make the search happen.

We don't know for sure which way is better. We notice some aspects as followings:

- Using portal: the process of setting up the search is easy and quick.
- Using @azure/search-documents: it is a bit more tedious to set up the search, but it gives us the flexibility to the index definition and rules when to update the index.

Other than the above points, we don't know what are the other pros/cons of those 2 ways?

Any insight on this would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While it's subjective based on the use case what the 'better' way is, typically for minimal business logic and simple data sources, you can use the Portal quickly to index and enrich documents.

You can check out the React Template we have that once you have an index you can seamlessly display UI elements like searching, filtering, sorting, and faceting documents.

https://github.com/dereklegenzoff/azure-search-react-template

You can also check out the Knowledge Mining Accelerator to show a step-by-step process on how to build a Cognitive Search solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-search-knowledge-mining/azure-search-knowledge-mining/

Comment: Thank you very much, Farazd, for the very helpful resources! So, may I ask if there is anything that we can do with the @azure/search-documents library but can't do via the Portal or vice versa?

Comment: You can find more about the REST API vs the Portal features at the docs below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/